# Understanding Multi-threading (boost) in bitcoin initialization

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

I am not familiar with boost in c++. Can any expert please explain in simple terms what is happening in the below code ? Is it like the logic in `ThreadScriptCheck` is scheduled to be run in background or how?

This is taken from bitcoin initialization (`src/init.cpp`). The classes are defined in `src/scheduler.h`

`AppInit2()`:

```
// Assume value of nScriptCheckThreads is 4

if (nScriptCheckThreads) {
    for (int i=0; i<nScriptCheckThreads-1; i++)
        threadGroup.create_thread(&ThreadScriptCheck);
}

// Start the lightweight task scheduler thread
CScheduler::Function serviceLoop = boost::bind(&CScheduler::serviceQueue, &scheduler);
threadGroup.create_thread(boost::bind(&TraceThread<CScheduler::Function>, "scheduler", serviceLoop));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `boost::thread_group` class doesn't do very much. It's basically just a container of threads. It doesn't really have any scheduling or dispatch functions. That this thread is part of a thread group doesn't really matter.

The `CScheduler` code allows a thread to run a task at a particular time. It requires a thread to run the various tasks that it schedules. This code creates a thread to runs those tasks for this `CScheduler` and adds it to the thread group.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. Also, can you point me out what those tasks (being run in `CScheduler`) exactly are? The LogPrintf above this code snippet in `src/init.cpp` mentions that it runs script verification, but I am unable to find relevant logic in the source code.

Comment: Also, `GenerateBitcoins` in `sec/miner.cpp` also creates a threadgroup with which it associates the `BitcoinMiner`. As per what I understand from your explanation, that this is just associating the thread in a group. But then how is the miner run in background?

Comment: The bitcoin daemon no longer runs a miner in the background, or at all for that matter. The scheduler is used for periodic tasks such as making outbound connections.

Comment: But where is the scheduler for `BitcoinMiner` ? There is no scheduler logic used for running the thread group associated with mining. `miner.cpp` has logic only for thread group creation.